# Information paradox and spacelike slices

Tags: general-relativity

I'm reading [S. Mathur's paper on the information paradox](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1038) and I can't seem to understand the reason why we choose spacelike slices. Is it because we want to have a global timelike vector so that we will be able to define the vacuum state "canonically"?

If that's the case what whould happen in Kruskal coordinates? If the horizon is non-singular, then there whould be no need for connector. Where would the "streching" take place, and where would the particles be created? Does the paradox even exist in this case?

Comment: I added a link to the paper I assume you're talking about. If you're talking about another paper, please replace it with the appropriate link.

Comment: Yes that's the paper I'm talking about. Thank you.